# ASP.NET Identity Framework ApplicationUser is not part of the model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I was searching for a solution for my problem but I didn't find it for my case.

I'm having two projects which shall be linked together. One of them is a database and the other one is an ASP.NET MVC project using the identity framework.

For using my own database I wrote:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyDataSource", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    [...]
}
```

But I'm getting the error message:
**The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.**

The solutions I found here were refering to inherit the ApplicationDbContext from the IdentityDbContext but that obviously didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very generic error.
If you are using model-first or db-first, check your connection string and if it auto generated by EF like this:

```
<add name="MyDataSource" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.***.csdl|res://*/Models.***.ssdl|res://*/M‌​odels.***.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=DB_Projectname;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Then change it to:

```
<add name="MyDataSource" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=DB_Projectname;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Yes, just delete model metadata and change provider name to System.Data.SqlClient.

Also, make sure that Identity is connected correctly. You can create an empty asp.net mvc project and compare Startup.cs and Startup.Auth.cs with your app.

Comment: Actually I can't declare the UserManagerFactory in my Startup.Auth.cs because VS doesn't import the necessary namespaces. Or do I need to implement it manually? What namespaces do I need for the UserManagerFactory?

Comment: You may have code like this: `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);`

And in Create method something like this: `var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>());`

Just add db context tp this line: `var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));`

Comment: Also, i added an example for UserManager here: https://gist.github.com/Vadimyan/9dae23f8051ea37a50f7
As You can see in line 148 we are using ApplicationUserManager instead of DbContext to manipulate user-entities.

Comment: I'm actually using the context for the manager in exactly this way.

Comment: OK, what line of code throws this exception? Have you got table for users in your DB? Please, show me your connectionString.

Comment: My connection string:  `<add name="MyDataSource" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.***.csdl|res://*/Models.***.ssdl|res://*/Models.***.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=DB_Projectname;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`
I have the tables in the DB. My DB project looks like the default created db + the addtional tables for other purposes. The line that throws the code is inside of my AccountController:

Comment: And looks like that: 
`var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false); `

Comment: Good. First of all you can delete metadata from your auto generated connection string and change provider to SqlClient:
`<add name="MyDataSource" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=DB_Projectname;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: I can't believe that, it fixed the problem. Just to shorten the connection string. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hurray, I'm glad we troubleshot it